# Number of integer solutions of $3x+y+z=23$

Tags: combinatorics

Calculate the number of nonnegative integer solutions of
$$3x+y+z=23.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Start from $x=0$ and you get $y+z=23$ and the total ordered pair $(y,z)=24$

Continue taking $x=0,1,2,....$ until it is non-negative and then add all the ordered pairs of $(y,z)$ to get the number of non-negative integer solutions.

Comment: That was the first thing I thought, but there’s an alternative way? Maybe using combinatorics?

Comment: @Lisbeth Yes, there is one formula. The number of solutions of the equation $x_1+x_2+....+x_p=n$ is $\dbinom{p-1}{n+p-1}$